# Switching off the magnetic coils in a Hall Effect Thruster

Tags: propulsion, advanced-propulsion, ion-thruster

Talking about Hall Effect Thrusters (HET), we can say that the presence of a hollow cathode is relevant to reach a good operation of the thruster. We also can plot the potential-x (trajectory of electrons) graph to see how they behave when approaching to the channel. **How would differ the potential-x plot if we switch off the magnetic coils?**